# Why did Luke's lightsaber end up in the snow?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

When Luke gets knocked out and taken by the snow yeti. How come his lightsaber is a ways away from him in the snow. Surely it should have still been on his belt or where he was knocked down.

**How did it get there?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lightsaber was still attached to Luke's belt after he was knocked unconscious.

[image]

The creature dragged him into its cave, then lifted him up to the ceiling.

Given the position of the lightsaber a few feet away from where Luke is hanging, it seems most likely that it either fell off of his belt while the creature was sticking him up there, or was pulled off by the Wampa and thrown aside.

---

From the film's [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(junior_novelization))

> He remembered his lightsaber. **He reached to his belt, but the
>   lightsaber was gone.** Oh, no! Don’t tell me it’s lost! Luke angled his
>   head, and spotted the lightsaber half buried in the snow on the floor
>   below him.

and from the film's [original screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html)

> Exhausted, he drops back into his hanging position.  **As he hangs
>   there,  he spies his lightsaber lying near a pile of his discarded
>   gear,** about  three feet out of reach.

Comment: Just rewatching it now but never seen the pile of his stuff!

Comment: No, in this case the screenplay and the film disagree with each other. You only see his lightsaber in the snow

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - The pile of discarded items is mentioned in both novels and makes an appearance in the original marvel graphic novelisation; https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4bfu.png but it's nowhere to be seen in any of the set photos. I guess they just changed their mind on the day.

Comment: A pile of discarded gear including his primary weapon suggests some level of intellect on the Wampa's part - maybe they changed it in the movie so as to not humanise the latest Jedi dismemberment victim?

Comment: @delinear - They also removed a scene where the Wampa broke into the base, another thing that would have made them seem more aggressive/intelligent.